# Collect users activity in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, redis

I desire to provide a fast ability to get status of user his availability.

It must be fastest reading data from storage.

Thus I chosed Redis storage for storing available status of each users.

So, besides that I need store more extended information about available users, such as region, time of login, etc.

For this purpose I got a Kafka, where this data is stored.

Question is, how to synchronise   Kafka and Redis?

Which sequence should be, first store event online users in Kafka, then sink it to Redis?

Second is store in Redis and asynchronously in Kafka.

I afraid a latency between Kafka and Redis for sink operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from the question, you want to store only user and userstatus in Redis and complete profile on Kafka.

I am not sure about the reason of choosing Kafka as your primary source of all data. Also, how are you planning to use the data stored there.

- If data storage in Kafka is really important to you, then I'd suggest to update your primary database first(Kafka or any) and then update cache.
- In this case, you need to do a sync operation on Kafka producer and once its successful, update ur cache.
- As your readd operations are only from redis - performance will not be impacted.
- But if opting sync producer might add little bit overhead beacuse of acknowledgement when compared to async.